# wb.UploadValue with NameValueCollection in Objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c, namevaluecollection

I have a C# code and I want to translate it to objective C.

```
var data = new NameValueCollection();
data["username"] = "abc";
data["password"] = "abc";
wb.UploadValues("https://abc.abc" + loginUrl, "POST", data);
```

I think it is possible over the NSMutableData but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot.